# How can I avoid picking up escape characters when reading from a document?

Tags: xml, xpath, escaping

I am trying to read some InnerText from an xml document. When I read it I get this string:

```
\r\n\t\t\tDemo submission\r\n\t\t
```

Im assumung these are escape characters that dictate new lines, spaces etc? What I'm wondering is how to read the InnerText from an XML document and ignore all these escape characters so that I just get:

```
Demo submission
```

Any help much appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a little rude :)

`fn:replace('\r\n\t\t\tDemo submission\r\n\t\t','\\t|\\n|\\r','')`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called "normalize". Use the `normalize-space` function: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space